# Create directory for imgs

Tags: windows, cmd, glassfish, glassfish-4, mkdir

I try to install glashfish4 to Windows.

The instructions mentions to crete a directory for images.

I open cmd and I do to the glashfish path with cd and I type:

```
mkdir -p /var/webapp/images
```

and the error I receive:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

What path could I set to create this directory?

Comment: The syntax is for linux based machines..

Comment: @AndrewL thank you I use some instructions please could you tell me what should I do in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is linux based as the command also uses the linux filesystem. Here is the documentation on `mkdir` for windows:

[Technet Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490930.aspx)

So:

```
mkdir "Drive:\path\to\new\directory"
```